# Is there an API I can use to query Offline Files results?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows-7, com

If you run `MobSync.exe` on a Windows 7 computer with Offline Files enabled, you can click "View sync results" to get a view of the Offline Files Sync history of your computer.

Does anyone know if there's an API to get this history, or is it necessary to parse through Event logs or the registry to do this?

I know about the [Offline Files API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but as far as I can tell, that doesn't give me any history of past syncs - only information about the current state of the Offline Files Cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any such API.